# VKSDK : How to translate code to swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, vk-sdk

I try to translate this code:

```
[[VKSdk instance] setUiDelegate:self];
```

i tried so:

```
VKSdk.instance().setUiDelegate(self)
```

But this is wrong!
Please help!

Comment: Well it seems to be right, what error message do you get?

Comment: error: Value of type 'VKSdk' has no member 'setUiDelegate'

Comment: I think I have found your Problem in the Frameworks git repository... Check out my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From where do you have the Objective-C code above? I have quickly read over the frameworks.h file and did not find something like that.

But I did find this:

```
VKSdk.initializeWithDelegate(self, andAppId: "")
```

Is that what you are searching for? Or does it have to be the `setUIDelegate`?

**UPDATE**

Wait I have found something else...

`VKSdkUIDelegate Protocol`.

Please try this:

```
VKSdk.instance().uiDelegate = self
```

[VK iOS SDK](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-ios-sdk/blob/master/library/Source/VKSdk.h)

Comment: Yes, this work! Thank you very much!

Comment: No Problem, stay coding mate :-)